# How to allow a user to enter a list of IP Ranges

Tags: usability

We have a screen where we currently edit an IP pool, that is, a list of IP ranges (1.1.1.1-1.1.1.100, 1.1.1.1-200.1.1.300). It's pretty hard to use because there's a single input and you have to select the one you currently want to edit.

[image: DHCP pool - Design 1]

An inline editing grid is being proposed

[image: DHCP pool - Design 2]

We're also thinking that an alternative would be to just allow them to enter them into a textarea, where each line is an IP range. This would have the benefit that administrators can create their entire pool on a text field and just paste it here. No add/edit/delete buttons.
[image]

One drawback would be that when validating it is that we'd have no way to highlight only the range that may be mis-formatted, it would only be a single error at the bottom.

I would appreciate any feedback and previous experience with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're heading in the right direction.

**Adding, editing, and deleting IP address records**

If you make the user select whether they're adding an IP address or a range, it will ultimately be easier to validate each record and provide good direction on formatting. (If the user wants to edit an IP address, the fields can simply become editable inline.) Examples:

Single IP address:
[image: Single IP address addition record]

IP address range:
[image: IP address range]

Of course, if your user needs to upload hundreds of IP addresses, you'll want to support bulk upload (and have the system do the heavy lifting of validation). That's usually done through a textarea (as shown in your example), or a CSV file upload.

**Validating multi-line uploads**

Some examples of multi-line validation patterns can be found in contact systems, like email marketing or CRMs - where the user uploads one record per line in a textarea or CSV file, which the system then validates line-by-line.

Rather than giving error feedback in a single line, the system creates a report of records that weren't imported, with the option for the user to correct or ignore them.

[image: Campaign Monitor email upload error]

[image: Constant Contact contact upload error]

If there's more than a few errors, the system should make it easy to do a bulk upload again, without drawing too much attention to duplicate entries. You could show a confirmation message at the end of a successful bulk upload, such as "230 records uploaded; 2 new, 228 existing."

Comment: Bulk entering is not the main feature, I just thought it'd be a nice to have, I don't think we want to make it a two step process considering most users are not going to be bulk entering.

Comment: Is the problem that you're trying to solve that *editing* IP addresses in bulk is difficult?

Comment: No, that would just be a nice side effect of using a textarea. The main feature is adding/deleting/editing some IP ranges

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer to provide info on that.

Comment: Thanks. Some comments: just a start IP is a valid range. Adding this option of choosing what type (range/single) adds a lot of busyness and requires a split workflow. We also don't want to have to edit only one record at a time, which is why we're going toward a list of text-fields (This is already in a popup after they click [edit pool]. Also we really

Comment: Can you tell me more about the use case for bulk-editing IP addresses and ranges? Do they change a lot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128003/discussion-between-izquierdo-and-juan-mendes).

Comment: I do not want bulk editing to be a concern, we have not been told there is a customer screaming for it. I only mentioned it because it was for free when using a textarea. Sorry, I can't continue the conversation now because I need to put the kids to sleep